# Error:Dependency is not Satisfiable: libqtcore5a(>=5.7.0)

Tags: linux-mint, virtualbox

I am trying to install virtual box from the oracle website, but I keep getting the error shown below. I tried to upgrade and update, but nothing works. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `apt-get install libqt5core5a`?

Comment: I did. it says everything is up-to-date

Comment: I am trying to install [TexMaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html) and I have the same problem.

Comment: Found this, https://www1.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2 and, http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gettingstarted.html not sure how to install on a Debian based distro (Debian, *untu, Mint etc.) though

Comment: I had the same  issue with Texmaker installation. I followed the installation process word to word as described [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu). And I installed Qt successfully. But for some reason double clicking the _texmaker_5.0.2_ubuntu_17_04_amd64.deb_ file would give me the err you are seeing. Everything is up to date with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. I tried downloading deb file several times, to rule out any issue with file downloading. Even tried restarting the computer several times. Finally, `sudo apt-get install texmaker` worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are trying to install Virtual Box try either of the following methods.

**Method 1: Command line**

The [installation guide](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html#install-linux-host) has documented detailed instructions which might help you. First try to follow these steps and if you have any question at any of the following steps the [general guide](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) might come handy, just scroll down and you would see more details for Linux.

Alternatively, you can also refer to this: [How to install Virtual Box on Linux Mint 18](https://youtu.be/DaeW3drCBls).

Steps:

1. Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` in your favorite text editor as root (gedit, Emacs, vim, nano, Visual Studio Code, etc.)

e.g.

```
$ sudo atom /etc/apt/sources.list
```

enter root password if prompted

2. add the following line to your /etc/apt/sources.list file:

*(For Linux mint, according to your version, replace 'xenial' by 'yakkety', 'vivid', 'utopic', 'trusty', 'raring', 'quantal', 'precise', 'lucid', 'jessie', 'wheezy', or 'squeeze', if needed.)*

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib
```

3. *Download and register public keys*

execute:

```
$ wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
$ wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

4. *To install Virtual Box,*

execute:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.2
```

5. *Finally, install dkms*

execute:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dkms
```

**Method 2: Via User Interface**

Try to see if you can get around it using either of the package manager UIs. I'd include all steps below, just in case if you run into any other issues

- Launch "Ubuntu Software Center" (alternatively `$ software-center`)
- Launch Synaptic Package manager (if not present, I can be installed by running `$ sudo apt-get install synaptic` ) ([FAQs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto))
- Once either software center or synaptic is launched, you can search for Virtual Box as shown below:

[image]

Now search for VirtualBox and then try to install it:

[image]

If you are in the synaptic package manager interface just search for "virtualbox" as shown below and select the entry that says just "virtualbox" (right click --> mark for installation) doing so, the program might and should ask you to install dependencies, you should accept the changes and click the apply button in the menu strip on top, a window would open for confirming changes. Verify your changes and click apply again, without changing any settings.

[image]

*References:*

- [Synaptic "How To..." - Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto)

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can install Qt:

**Prerequisites**

Install: g++ & OpenGL libraries

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1
sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev -y
```

**Download & Install**

Meanwhile you can [download](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2) Qt from [here](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2).

Example:

```
wget http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.7/5.7.0/qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.7.0.run
```

Next, adjust permissions:

```
chmod +x qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.7.0.run
```

Now, you can start the installation process:

```
./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.7.0.run
```

At this point you should see on screen instructions to follow installation process as below:

[image: Installation Screen 1]
[image: Installation Screen 2]
[image: Installation Screen 3]

Now here you can change the installation path if you need/want to and carry on the installation
[image: Installation Screen 4]

Once your installation is complete (depending on the components you have installed) you might see something as following. In my case I did not change any default setting and Qt installation was smooth for me.

Below is a screen shot of Qt Creator and Qt Configuration applications after installation:
[image: Qt Creator and Qt Configuration applications after installation]

**References:**

1. [Here is the perm link](https://wiki.qt.io/index.php?title=Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu&oldid=29811) to the wiki page from Qt. Useful for step
   by step documentation and [troubleshooting](https://wiki.qt.io/index.php?title=Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu&oldid=29811#Troubleshooting) . I am on Ubuntu, but
   being a Debian based distro, it should work on Mint as well.
2. https://forum.qt.io/topic/24693/how-to-install-qt-5-0-x-in-linux-mint
   https://windyweather.net/2015/03/19/qtframework-install/
3. https://windyweather.net/2015/03/19/qtframework-install/
4. If you need, here is the [related post on Qt's forums](https://forum.qt.io/topic/59062/qt-5-5-0-problem-running-examples-solved/5)

Comment: I tried to do what you say, but it is still not working

Comment: When you say you "tried" does it mean that Qt was installed but you still are having issues with Virtual Box installation?

Comment: Qt is installed and still having issues with Virtual Box